# Display alerts for current user only

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In sharepoint 2007 user alerts page, can we disable the dropdown box of user selection?
We want to show the alerts only of current logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the alert is not the only solution. You will have to create a custom solution with the following

1. Custom solution to update a Temp List or file whenever someone logs in or logs out
2. Anothe Application Page to read from the above list and display their alerts.

Comment: I apologies for late reply..
We have used default page so I didn't tried this.
Thank you for taking time